# Javascript navigation not being stopped on last page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have the following code to navigate between pages in an image gallery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function leftArrowPressed() {
        var url = $('#img_back').attr('href');
        window.location = url;
    }
    function rightArrowPressed() {
        var url = $('#img_next').attr('href');
        window.location = url;
    }
    document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
        evt = evt || window.event;
        switch (evt.keyCode) {
            case 37:
                leftArrowPressed();
                break;
            case 39:
                rightArrowPressed();
                break;
        }
    };
</script>
```

And everything works great. Unless I try to go back from the first page (page 0 doesn't exist) or forward beyond the last (current) page (Also doesn't exist). The number of pages is constantly going to change, so I need to be able to go beyond a hard number, but it would be nice if it would end at the min and max pages.

For example, I currently have 2 images in the gallery. If I'm on page 1 and I hit the left arrow, it brings me to another page. I want it to do nothing in that situation. If I"m on page 2 I want it to stop me from going to page 3 if page 3 doesn't exist. I guess I'm basically asking if there's a way to check if the page **exists** before redirecting to it? How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Preventing from going to page 0 is easy, that can be hardcoded, but you need your code to know how many images there are in the gallery for the other part.

Comment: check `$('#img_next').length` before trying to get its href to make sure its matching, if it doesnt match then you dont have a next page so just return. apply same to _back

Comment: Do you have an HTML element with ID 'img_next' if your are currently seeing the last page?

Comment: If you actually *know* how many pages there are, then that number and whatever current page you're on need to be in your script as well.  With those numbers, you can check that you're not out of bounds in your functions.

Comment: Why is `$('#img_back').attr('href');` set if it does not exist?

Comment: @PatrickEvans I am unsure of how I would go about doing this, would you be able to give me an example?
@guli the element & id are there, but there is no `<a href="">` it's instead a `<span>` with the id if the link doesn't exist.
@Crontab I am trying to make this as flexible as possible, the gallery automatically takes the images and assigns the pages and is able to link to them as they are added/removed.
@epascarello there is no href in the case of _prev of p1 and _next of (last page(which is currently 2)).

Comment: look at guli's answer, does the same as i suggested only he test directly against url value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
function leftArrowPressed() {
    var url = $('#img_back').attr('href');
    if(!url)
        return;
    window.location = url;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I feel silly for not realizing there was such a simple solution. Thank you! EDIT: I wish I could upvote you, but I am unable to do so just yet. It is accepted though, so thank you.